# Can an existing exhaust fan with a light and night light be replaced with just an exhaust fan and a seperate can light in the shower?

Tags: electrical

We are remodeling our bathroom and in our shower we have an exhaust fan with a light and night light combo which are connected to three different switches.  We are replacing our exhaust fan with a better one but it does not have a light in it so we wanted to put a LED can light that was made for the shower.  Is this possible using the existing wires from where our original exhaust fan is to install both the exhaust fan and can light and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely.

Install the recessed light over the shower and use the junction box attached to the lights to then extend the wiring to the new fan location. You'll obviously need new wire between the light and fan.